# Error: "Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation"

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I get the following error `Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation`

when I submit the login form and I don't know how to fix it 
Here is my code

```js
const page = await chromium.newPage();
await page.goto("This is a Beautiful URL");
await page.type("#user",this.username)
await page.type("#pass",this.password)     
await page.click("#login_submit")
```

after page.click, then I get the error

```
Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hard to say without a [mcve] that includes the site. Chances are, though, `click` triggers a nav and that needs to be dealt with: `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click("#login_submit")])`

Comment: ohhh my god thank youuuuu u helped my life 999999.99% alot